# Tabularize ansible task result stdout_lines

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Team,
I read [this post](https://ansible-project.narkive.com/qA91wlom/how-to-correctly-print-a-multiline-stdout) and this seems to be no solution. so checking here..

my requirement is I have below output which i want to nicely print in rows/columns.
Task: calculate directory size on a linux node.

```
- name: Calculate directories size
  shell: du -sk {{ directories }} 2> /dev/null
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: dir_usage
  tags: tag_directory_usage

- name: Output results
  debug:
    var: dir_usage.stdout_lines
  ignore_errors: yes
  tags: tag_directory_usage
```

vars

```
#variables
directories: "/home /lib"
```

actual output

```
3  TASK [node_operations : Output results] ****************************************
19:05:53  Wednesday 24 March 2021  02:05:53 +0000 (0:00:07.828)       0:05:32.098 ******* 
19:05:53  ok: [node1] => {
19:05:53      "dir_usage.stdout_lines": [
19:05:53          "34988\t/home",
19:05:53          "0\t/lib"
19:05:53      ]
19:05:53  }
```

desired output : sampling only for two directories

```
|Dir  |Size   |
|-----|-------|
|/home|34988  |
|/lib |0      |
```

Comment: Ansible isn't designed to generate formatted output on `stdout`. If you want formatted output, use the `template` module and write your formatted text to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I found super dirty way to 'print' in Ansible without any decorations.

https://medium.com/opsops/how-to-print-on-screen-in-ansible-9c366f881f5a

It basically hijacks stdout of ansible-playbook console and writes into it directly. Works on Linux (only?).

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
   - shell: "echo '{{'='*10}} {{red}}H{{green}}E{{cyan}}L{{red}}L{{green}}O{{cyan}}!{{CSI}}0m {{'='*10}}' > /dev/tty"
  vars:
    CSI: "\x1B["
    red: '{{CSI}}31m'
    green: '{{CSI}}32m'
    cyan: '{{CSI}}36m'
```